# ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import, importerror

For some reason, I can't use the `Tkinter` (or `tkinter`, on Python 3) module.
After running the following command in the python shell:

```
import Tkinter
```

or this, in Python 3:

```
import tkinter
```

I got this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'

or this:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

What could be the reason for these errors and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 655, accepted):

You probably need to install it using something similar to the following:

- For Ubuntu or other distros with Apt:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python3-tk
  ```
- For Fedora:

  ```
  sudo dnf install python3-tkinter
  ```

You can also mention a Python version number like this:

- ```
  sudo apt-get install python3.7-tk
  ```
- ```
  sudo dnf install python3-tkinter-3.6.6-1.fc28.x86_64
  ```

Finally, import `tkinter` (for Python 3) or `Tkinter` (for Python 2), or choose at runtime based on the version number of the Python interpreter (for compatibility with both):

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    import tkinter as tk
else:
    import Tkinter as tk
```

Comment: It was the change in capitalization (Tkinter to tkinter) that got me - everyone now needs to update all of their sample code :)

Comment: Why does it need to be installed if it is a [standard python interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter)?

Comment: and for macOS, `brew install python-tk`

Comment: finally for Windows and win32, remember to check the `Tcl support for Python 3.11` when installing.

Comment: MacOS - if using MacPorts rather than Homebrew, something along the lines of the following: `python --version; port search python | grep tk`  followed by the like of: `sudo port install py311-tkinter`

Comment: this was very handy for a multiple python version install ( eg 3.8 and 3.10)

Answer (score 93):

As you are using Python 3, the module has been renamed to `tkinter`, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html):

> Note Tkinter has been renamed to tkinter in Python 3. The 2to3 tool
>   will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to
>   Python 3.

Answer (score 86):

If you're using python 3.9 on Mac, you can simply install `tkinter` using brew:

```py
brew install python-tk@3.9
```

This fixed it for me.

Edit:
As mentioned by others, you can also use the general command to install the latest version:

```bash
brew install python-tk
```

Answer (score 60):

For Windows, make sure to **check in the Python install the optional feature "tcl/tk and IDLE"**. Otherwise you get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

If Python is already installed without this optional feature, you need to amend the installation by launching again the Python installer and selecting `Modify`.

NB: you won't be able `pip install tkinter`, don't bother trying!

Comment: You are right, Python "embeddable zip file" don't contain tk, we should download the "executable installer" and don't forget to select the option "tcl/tk and IDLE"

Comment: You can amend a python installation launching again the python installer and selecting "Modify". At that point you can check the "tcl/tk and IDLE" checkbox and get the module you need.

Comment: As another note, Python's "embeddable zip file" doesn't contain pip, so that has to be installed first. (From beginner python user)

Answer (score 45):

To install the Tkinter on popular Linux distros:

**Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt install python3-tk -y
```

**Fedora:**

```
sudo dnf install -y python3-tkinter
```

**Arch:**

```
sudo pacman -Syu tk --noconfirm
```

**REHL/CentOS6/CentOS7:**

```
sudo yum install -y python3-tkinter
```

**OpenSUSE:**

```
sudo zypper in -y python-tk
```

Comment: -1; [`tkintertable`](https://pypi.org/project/tkintertable/) is not the same thing as the built-in [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) module.

Comment: Still: `import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`

Comment: tkinter is a standard-library module, and can't be installed with pip. `tkintertable` **is not the same thing**, that's just a project that builds on top of tkinter.

Comment: Note that this seems not to fix existing virtual environments, but only ones created after this point.

Comment: @tsbertalan virtual environments can be created in varying ways depending on configuration options and the platform. If the entire standard-library folder was symlinked rather than being copied, the virtual environment should be updated automatically. Otherwise it will need to be recreated.

Answer (score 25):

For Mac use:

```
brew install python-tk
```

Answer (score 20):

You might need to install for your specific version, I have known cases where this was needed when I was using many versions of python and one version in a virtualenv using for example python 3.7 was not importing tkinter I would have to install it for that version specifically.

For example

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-tk
```

No idea why - but this has occured.

Answer (score 14):

## Installing Tkinter

```sh
python -m pip install tk-tools
```

##### or

```sh
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

Comment: None of the pip commands worked for me (in a python 3.8 virtualenv). All that worked was the apt one.

Comment: I'm confused by why multiple answers here propose using `pip` to install arbitrary PyPI modules that *depend* on the built-in `tkinter` module (like `tk-tools` here, or `tkintertable` in an answer below) as a solution to the built-in `tkinter` module not being available. It seems unlikely that that could possibly help, and even if it does somehow work, it's a pretty ugly solution, since you're left with the arbitrary third-party module installed that you probably don't want.

Comment: **Do not use Pip. It cannot help solve the problem.**

Answer (score 10):

For **Windows 10** using either VSCode or PyCharm with Python 3.7.4 - make sure Tk is ticked in the install. I tried `import tkinter as xyz` with upper/lower **t** and **k**'s and *all variants* without luck.

What works is:

```
import tkinter
import _tkinter
tkinter._test()
```

An example in action:

```
import tkinter
import _tkinter

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

root = tkinter.Tk()

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tkinter.Frame(root, bg='red')
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think direclty importing `_tkinter` has any effect. `tkinter` automatically will import that.

Comment: @BryanOakley *I don't think this has any effect*. I can swear on anything this was the fix and it was for at least 5 others. It's got to be a bug then.

Comment: Why is importing _tkinter needed? What is the problem this addresses? How is this problem solved? Programming should be deterministic and not randomly trying things. On Ubuntu 20.04, I could remove this line and the script worked.

Comment: That probably deserves a new question,. This is Windows 10 specific and while python is x-platform it's not seamless.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/25905540/4539999 - python 3 `import tkinter` # notice lowercase 't' in tkinter here

Answer (score 7):

check the python version you have installed by using command `python --version`

check for the Tk module installed correctly from following code

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Check if you are using open-source OS then

check the tkinter module in the following path
**/home/python/site-packages/tkinter**
change the path accordingly your system

Answer (score 7):

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.10-tk
```

Answer (score 6):

On CentOS7, to get this working with Python2, I had to do:

```
yum -y install tkinter
```

Noting this here because I thought that there would be a pip package, but instead, one needs to actually install an rpm.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that when you are running your python code that it is in the **python3** context. I had the same issue and all I had to do was input the command as:

```
sudo python3 REPLACE.py
```

versus

```
sudo python REPLACE.py
```

the latter code is incorrect because tkinter is apparently unnavailable in python1 or python2.

Comment: Why are you running with sudo? Python does not require it.

Comment: Python doesn't but if you are using linux and have the python file in a restricted section it can help.

Comment: ... it might help.  But you should operate on principle of least access. Randomly applying `sudo` to things is a recipe for bad irreversible mistakes.  Don't `sudo` unless it's actually needed.

Answer (score 4):

For **Windows**, try to reinstall Python and make sure that during the installation process in the "Optional Features" it has the "tcl/tk and IDLE" option **enabled**.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install it and import them your project like that :

this code import to command line :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

after import tkinter your project :

```
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: Generally, it's discouraged to import * because there could be possible package conflicts. It also makes it difficult for other developers to easily see what was imported and how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Answer (score 3):

I resolved my issue in the PyCharm do following

1. Install Python Interpreter from https://www.python.org/
2. PyCharm > Preferences > Python Interpreter > Add
3. Select installed interpreter
4. In the run configuration select the newly installed interpreter

I also made a video instruction what I did https://youtu.be/awaURBnfwxk

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter should come with the latest Python, I don't think it comes with Python2. I had the same problem but once. I upgraded to Python 3.8 Tkinter was installed.

Answer (score 1):

if it doesnot work in pycharm you can add the module in the project interpreter by searching in +button python-tkinter and download it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use 2 types of methods for importing libraries

1. work with `import library`
2. work with `from library import *`

You can load tkinter using these ways:

1. `from tkinter import*`
2. `import tkinter`

Answer (score 0):

tkinter comes with python... uninstall python, reinstall it, you're done

Comment: that is an option for no one ?

Answer (score 0):

Check apt for tasks, it may be marked for removed

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then check and install needed

Answer (score 0):

On Linux it is possible to have installed two different versions of Python in my case 3.11 and 3.10. Only 3.10 was working with tkinter. 3.10 binary was located in my /usr/bin/python3 and 3.11 was located in /usr/local/sbin/python3. You can either specifically source the version you need or if you are SURE you don't need 3.11 at the moment, you can `sudo cp /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/sbin/python3` assuming your working version is in bin like mine is.

Answer (score -1):

```
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *   ## notice capitalized T in Tkinter 
except ImportError:
    try:
        # for Python3
        from tkinter import *   ## notice lowercase 't' in tkinter here
    except:
        try:
            print "Download Tkinter" ##python 2
        except SyntaxError:
            print("Download Tkinter") ##python 3
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have pip on your path, you could (in your command prompt) just type
`pip install tkinter`
Most versions of python already come with tkinter.

Comment: tkinter is a standard-library module, and can't be installed with pip.

Answer (score -2):

--------- WORKED ON PYTHON 2.7------------

Install all below packages

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install python-tk
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt install picolisp
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install -I pillow
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Comment: Why are you installing `git`, and `PIL`? Also why are you installing another programming language (`picolisp`)? Btw you are installing tkinter (`sudo apt-get install python-tk`) twice. You can shorten this answer to just: `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` and `sudo apt-get install python-tk`.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly you should test your python idle to see if you have tkinter:

```py
import tkinter

tkinter._test()
```

Trying typing it, copy paste doesn't work.

So after 20 hours of trying every way that recommended on those websites figured out that you can't use "tkinter.py" or any other file name that contains "tkinter..etc.py". If you have the same problem, just change the file name.

Answer (score -4):

cmd - terminal

pip install tkinter

Comment: tkinter is a standard-library module, and can't be installed with pip.