# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' in QGIS

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, qgis

In Qgis when I add the following code in a .py file and try to reload it in QGIS:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

print(file_path)
```

throws this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

But when I create a .py file with the same instructions and then I execute the program, there is no issue, the program open a window. Why? I have been searching but none of the answers works for me.

Comment: QGIS incorporates its own stand-alone Python which appears not to include Tkinter support. I can [find quite a few useful links about this with a simple web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=qgis+tkinter).

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to install it

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

I have been using Tkinter for a while now. Why don't you try this and let me know if it worked?

```
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *   ## notice capitalized T in Tkinter 
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *   ## notice lowercase 't' in tkinter here
```

for more detail [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter)

Comment: When I run the command python -m tkinter a window pop up, so... I think there is but is like Qgis can't find it.