# Python/Tkinter : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tkinter, tcl, pyenv

This is my first post StackOverflow, I will try to make it as correct and complete as possible if you have any tips to improve my post I will gladly accept it.

I'm having trouble running code written in Python that uses Tkinter.

I will try to describe in detail my actions to facilitate the identification of the error.

I started a course at Coursera on DSP (Digital Signal Processing) where it is suggested to install a tool written in python (and a little bit of C). I'm using Arch Linux.

link on Github:
[sms-tools repo](http://sms-tools%20repo)

Using *pyenv/virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper* I created an environment with Python 3.7.5, as recommended in the "How to use" section of the repository.

I installed the required libraries in my environment by pip:

`%pip install ipython numpy matplotlib scipy cython`

I compiled some C functions in the *"/sms-tools/software/models/utilFunctions_C"*

directory with the following command:

`%python compileModule.py build_ext --inplace`

Finally, I run the models GUI in the directory *"/sms-tools/software/models_interface"*

`%python models_GUI.py`

and I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models_GUI.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Tkinter import *   ## notice capitalized T in Tkinter 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models_GUI.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tkinter import *   ## notice lowercase 't' in tkinter here
  File "~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I will now describe some of my attempts to solve the problem:

Looking at [Tkinter section in Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) I tried installing Tcl and Tk.

`%sudo pacman -S tk`

but it was already installed. after that I tried installing with pip:

`%pip install tk`

and

`%pip install tkinter`

and the error remains the same.

I also tried to create a symlink with this code:
`%ln -s /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _tkinter.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

the symlink was created in the following folders:

`~/.ve/Coursera_DSP/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload`

and

`.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload`

But I still get the same error.

I appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions and I apologize for the language errors since English is not my mother tongue.

After an incessant search on the internet, I believe the problem is related to pyenv and TCL/TK.
I don't understand much about the subject but I suspect that in the creation of the environment by virtualenv python has lost the connection with TCL/TK. Does that make any sense?

Comment: An observation: tkinter needs to be part of the Python installation, and can't be installed by pip.

Comment: You don't need to install `tkinter` externally into python it is a built-in library. Secondly, I see in the error you posted that you are using `Tkinter` with capital `T` somewhere in your program while you should use `tkinter` with a small `t`.

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad that's an error handler, it tries Tkinter for python 2.x and if it fails it tries tkinter for python 3.x

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad Tkinter is pretty often (e.g., in Linux, or mac OS with MacPorts or Homebrew) something that you install as a separate package from Python. The exact name of the package varies. The _vital_ thing is to get that set up before building any virtual environments because tkinter's packaging is weird. (It's a heck of a lot more finickey than Tcl/Tk themselves, which are moderately easy to make relocatable and installable as a user without special trickery.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is **step by step guide** to make IDLE and `tkinter` work. Working for me on macOS Catalina. Should be easily adapted to Linux environment:

1. install `tcl-tk` with Homebrew. In shell run `brew install tcl-tk`
2. in shell run `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
3. reload shell by quitting `Terminal` app or run `source ~/.zshrc`
4. after reloaded check that `tck-tk` is in `$PATH`. Run `echo $PATH | grep --color=auto tcl-tk`. As the result you should see your $PATH contents with `tcl-tk` highlighted
5. now we run three commands from Homebrew's output from step #1

   1. in shell run `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"`
   2. in shell run `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"`
   3. in shell run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig"`
6. if you have your Python version already installed with `pyenv` then uninstall it with `pyenv uninstall <your python version>`. E.g. `pyenv uninstall 3.8.2`
7. set environment variable that will be used by `python-build`. In shell run `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'"`
   *Note: in future use `tck-tk` version that actually installed with Homebrew. At the moment of posting `8.6` was the actual*
8. finally install Python with `pyenv` with `pyenv install <version>`. E.g. `pyenv install 3.8.2`

**Test**

1. in shell run `pyenv global <verion that you've just installed>`
2. now check IDLE. In shell run `idle`. You should see IDLE window without any warnings and "text printed in red".

[image: IDLE window run from Terminal. No warnings]

3. now check `tkinter`. In shell run `python -m tkinter -c "tkinter._test()"`. You should see test window like on the image:

[image: tkinter test window]

That's it!

**My environment:**

check this is something went wrong executing steps above:

1. macOS Catalina
2. `zsh` (included in macOS Catalina) = **"shell" above**
3. Homebrew (installed with instructions from Homebrew official website)
4. `pyenv` (installed with Homebrew and PATH updated according to `pyenv` official readme from GitHub)
5. Python `3.8.x` - `3.9.x` (installed with `pyenv install <version>` command)

Comment: In order for the env var in step 7 to take effect, Step 7 and 8 should be done on the same command, i.e. `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS=“—with-tcltk-includes=‘-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include’ —with-tcltk-libs=‘-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6’” pyenv install 3.8.2`

Comment: worked for me, using MacOS Sonoma + pyenv + python 3.12

Answer (score 8):

mac Monterey (M1)

```
brew install python-tk
```

python 3.9.10

Answer (score 3):

My basic install of linux mint 20 contains python3.
On windows machines this includes the `tkinter` package.
My solution was to

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

and live was sunny again.

Answer (score 2):

I created a venv using Python 3.10.5 (alternate version to default 3.8). Tkinter failed to install when I used the command "sudo apt-get install python3-tk"; however, when I used "sudo apt-get install python3.10-tk", the module installed properly.  Apparently, using the specific python3 version made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find any solution I just uninstalled my whole environment system (pyenv pyenv-virtualenv virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper) and installed conda instead. Now everything works.
Probably I messed up with pyenv installation.

Thank you all :D

Comment: At work, we recommend installing components like tkinter before building any virtual environments. And we also have considerable workarounds for some weird platforms. Well, actually, all platforms are sometimes weird…