# Can't use python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, homebrew

I have been trying to import Tkinter into my program, but I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

When I try `python3 -m tkinter`:

```
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I've tried installing Tkinter using pip/python, but it isn't working. Previously it was working, but after running

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/dot /usr/local/bin/dot
```

it stopped working.

Comment: Is there a graphical user interface on that computer? Also how did you install python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/Tkinter : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\_tkinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987762/python-tkinter-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tkinter)

Comment: `tkinter` is a wrapper on stript language `tcl` and its GUI modul `tk` and you may have to install them using probably `homebrew` - but normally `tkinter should be installed with all needed elements.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have python 3 or higher?
Did you import tkinter?

try this: `py -3 -m pip install tkinter` (for windows)

Comment: The install is only for windows, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I read "opt" so I assume you are using Linux. The solution to your problem should be:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

UPDATE: Only now, later, I notice that you use `import _tkinter`. That's no good. You should use `import tkinter`, because with import _tkinter you import the C-based cpython library and you don't have access to the Python classes