# How can I add the tkinter to the pyproject.toml in poetry?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-poetry

```
  File "project.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

This is always happens when I want to run my project with poetry run python project.py but if I run natively it's working flawlessly.
So I guess the problem is to add the Tkinter to the .toml file but when I add tk to the dependencies it's not working properly. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I add tk to the dependencies it's not working properly"? How exactly is it "not working properly"?

Comment: @ForceBru It means the tkinter.filedialog is not included when I would like to run the project.py. But all the other dependencies working perfectly if I remove all tkinter components.

Comment: do you run Python 3 or Python 2? In Python 2 it could have name `Tkinter` with upper `T`. Do you run it on some Linux server? In most systems `tkinter` is installed with `Python` but on some Ubuntu Servers it needed to install manually library `python-tkinter` using tool `apt` (because Ubuntu Server doesn't have graphic mode so it can't display GUIs - so Python doesn't need `tkinter` module and it is not installed with Ubuntu Server)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. `python -m tkinter` works fine (opens a mini Tk test window) but `poetry run python -m tkinter` fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'` (and some preceding error text too). Since `tkinter` is part of the std lib, you can't install it — it's not on PyPi, or anywhere — just like how you can't install `os`, `json`, etc. Not sure what the solution is here except to ask the poetry devs to fix the issue or install the necessary libraries separately as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/59987762/5496433 and related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I did also have this issue, but as @furas did mention tkinter is not installed by default on some ubuntu serverion(i run (in windows)ubuntu 22.04 LTS) with Poetry (version 1.6.1) and python 3.10

So I did have to install tkinter with apt-get by: sudo apt-get install python3-tk

Now tkinter is installed but it still cant be added to the .tomel, but if i dont have it added and run the project with "poetry run python project.py" it do run without any problem. It seams to be the same with all standard Python libraries. My .toml is then:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "test-gui"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["JonTheBaboon"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
pillow = "^10.1.0"
tk = "^0.1.0"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

You mentions tk, if you run "poetry add tk", you will get another package "TensorKit", see the poetry.lock file:

```
name = "tk"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "TensorKit is a deep learning helper between Python and C++."
optional = false
python-versions = "*"
```