# I get this error when importing Tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to learn Tkinter in python but when I try to import it, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

I don't know what to do, can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: No, I'm using mac.

Comment: If you are using windows, search cmd in the search bar and click the first result that comes up. then, type in pip install tkinter and you should be fine.

Comment: I did that, but it gives me an error too

Comment: Ok this should help and use method 1:[https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Tkinter](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Tkinter)

Comment: it gives me the same error

Comment: @BoxifyMC Pip **cannot be used to install Tkinter, or any other standard library component**. If it is missing, the problem must be addressed in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version of Python you are using, you need to import tkinter in a different way. In python 2, the code is this:
`from Tkinter import *`.
In Python 3, you should use `from tkinter import *`.

The difference is that the first letter in tkinter is capitalized in Python 2, while in Python 3 it is all lowercase.

If you are not sure what version of Python you are using, open the Python Shell and it will show you.

Comment: I know, I am using python 3.8. I import it like 'from tkinter import *' but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter?rq=1.And if it doesn't work then look the the right on the "Linked" category and you'll find other similar questions.