# tkinter : NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

I use mac, learning python, using pycharm

code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

result:

```
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

Then, I try to install python3-tk

I type `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` in terminal

result:

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Then, I try to update

I type `sudo apt-get update`

result:

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

How can I fix the problem. Please help, thank you!!

Comment: It works on my machine. What OS/distribution are you using, and what version of python and TKinter?

Comment: Is your file name `tkinter` or something? If module was not found, it should have given some errors in the first line itself.

Comment: @OctaveL
OS Catalina
about the version of python, thats another problem
I have installed version 3.8
but the default version is 2.7
just like pygame, I used many methods to install it to version 3.8
but it still be installed to 2.7
I select "inherit global site-package" in pycharm to fix that

Comment: @OctaveL and I just check tkinter version by "pip list" and I cant find the name of tkinter. Is that mean i haven't install it yet?

Comment: @CoolCloud no, file name is not tkinter. what do you mean by the first line. The first line of my python file?

Comment: First line was `from tkinter import *` they would give a `ModuleNotFoundError` if `tkinter` was not found, anyway have you tried `sudo dnf install python3-tkinter`. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter)

Comment: @CoolCloud just try: result :  sudo: dnf: command not found.

Comment: is something wrong with my setup of python? any modules or package must be installed before using python?

Comment: @HoOonLau You can't use `apt-get` or `dnf` because they're for Debian based Linux distributions and Red Hat based distros, respectively - you're on macOS. I don't use macOS but the issue here is definitely in your python setup or your tkinter installation, I can't really help much more. Try `brew install tcl-tk`, I suppose.

Comment: Why not just try the same code on python IDLE and try if it works?

Comment: Do this: `import tkinter; print(tkinter.__file__)`. It will tell you if you're importing the standard tkinter module or some file that has the same name.