# No module named 'torch'

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to solve this Error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
I did the installation of Pytorch using this command:
`conda install pytorch -c pytorch`
but when I import torch I got the message above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter)

Comment: What is the output of `which python`? Or `pyhon3`, whatever you used to run python.

Comment: This was wrongly closed. It **should still be a duplicate, but** I have not yet identified a proper canonical (I may have to create one). This question is about problems with installing third-party libraries and making sure they are installed *for the same copy of Python* that will run the code. Questions about Tkinter **should not** be used to close such a question as duplicates, because: a) Tkinter **is not** a third-party library; b) there are **two different common reasons** why Tkinter imports commonly fail, **neither of which** is the same problem as here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be on another conda environment.
try:

```
conda env list
```

and find the environment that you have installed pytorch on.
then use:

```
conda activate NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV
```

to swtich to that environment and run your program there.

Comment: this was my problem Thank you