# No module named 'tkinter' and doesn't import

Tags: python, tkinter

I installed tkinter and my python version is 3.6.9 but it still doesn't import

```
import tkinter

from tkinter import *
root = tkinter.Tk(  )
for r in range(3):
   for c in range(4):
      tkinter.Label(root, text='R%s/C%s'%(r,c),
         borderwidth=1 ).grid(row=r,column=c)
root.mainloop(  )
```

error is     import tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's happening because of an installation error. So, please make sure that tkinter is installed properly.
like, for ubuntu or other distros with apt,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

additionally, for me, it's always the best way to run a project is via a **virtual environment**. So, after checking the installation, if it again doesn't run, try this after creating a virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

If you are importing all from tkinter (from tkinter import *), you should call functions not like:

```
tkinter.Tk()
```

But like:

```
Tk()
```

Comment: it still doesn't work :(

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked. The code fails on the very first line.