# ModuleNotFound (tkinter), but I've tried everything I found and nothing works

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, visual-studio-code, tkinter

Linux, pop_os, vs code, python3

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Hello World")
win.mainloop()
```

`python main.py` -> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'`

`python3-tk` and `python-tk` already installed with apt

`python --version` (in vs code terminal) -> `Python 3.9.9`

`pip3 install tk` (in vs code terminal) -> `Requirement already satisfied: tk in /var/data/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.1.0)`

`pip3 install tkinter` (in vs code terminal) -> `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)` 
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter`

Comment: Try running your script from a terminal (outside vscode). If that works, the problem lies with vscode. Personally I would suggest using a text editor instead of an IDE.

Comment: You cannot install tkinter with pip.

Comment: @RolandSmith worked, however how can I make it work inside VS code itself? Or am I stuck with having to launch the program with an external terminal?

Comment: There's no technical reason that you can't run it in vscode. Your vscode just isn't configured to have the path where the version of python with tkinter exists.

Comment: You might check out this link [Installing tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter).  That's what I had to do to install it on Linux Mint.

Comment: If you search for "vscode select python interpreter" you will find several links on how to configure vscode for Python.

Comment: It worked for me. I suggest you re-install Python.

Comment: **No part of the standard library, including Tkinter, can be installed using Pip.** Whatever `tk` package you installed **is not** the Tkinter standard library. The `apt` install of `python3-tk`, only affects the system Python. If you are using a Python built from source, you need to rebuild it *after* installing a *development* Tk package. Please see the linked duplicate for details. If, on the other  hand, you want to make VS Code use the system Python (where Tkinter should work, now that `python3-tk` is installed), that is a totally separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you can successfully run the code in **the external terminal**, it indicates that this is not a package problem.

In the comments, Roland Smith said clearly that you need to configure the **correct interpreter** for vscode by the following way:

1. use shortcut **"ctrl+shift+P"**
2. type `"Python: select interpreter"`
3. choose the correct interpreter.