# Can't Run Turtle module on Python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am learning OPP and the tutorial I am following is tinkering with the Turtle Module, however when I run this basic code:

```
from turtle import Turtle
from turtle import Screen


timmy = Turtle()
print(timmy)
timmy.shape("turtle")
timmy.color("red","green")

my_screen = Screen()
print(my_screen.canvheight)
my_screen.exitonclick()
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.11 /Users/salaheddinefathallah/Files of Salah/Programming/01. Python/03. App Brewery/147 - First OPP Project/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/salaheddinefathallah/Files of Salah/Programming/01. Python/03. App Brewery/147 - First OPP Project/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from turtle import Turtle
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter)

Comment: Have you tried installing *tkinter*(`pip install tk-tools`) like it says? (I hope you are not using an older version of turtle which uses an outdated version of tkinter or something as its says '**_tkinter** with an underscore')

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the game but have been having some weird issues trying to start with tkinter, where it's installed but the window either glitches out or gives the ModuleNotFound error above.

My solution to both-

Make sure x-code is installed:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Tinker relies on Tcl-Tk framework:

```
brew install tcl-tk
```

Ensures python version is installed with TK support:

```
brew install python-tk@3.12
```

This just tells pyenv to use the Tcl-Tk installation from Homebrew for building Python:

```
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" pyenv install 3.12.2
```

And then to test:

```
python -m tkinter
```