# How to manipulate figures while a script is running in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

#### Introduction

As I am coming from [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab), I am used to an interactive interface where a script can update figures while it is running. During the processing each figure can be re-sized or even closed. This probably means that each figure is running in its own thread which is obviously not the case with [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib).

IPython can imitate the Matlab behavior using the magic command `%pylab` or `%matplotlib` which does something that I don't understand yet and which is the very point of my question.

My goal is then to allow standalone Python scripts to work as Matlab does (or as IPython with `%matplotlib` does). In other words, I would like this script to be executed from the command line. I am expecting a new figure that pop-up every 3 seconds. During the execution I would be able to zoom, resize or even close the figure.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def do_some_work(): 
    time.sleep(3)

for i in range(10):
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
    plt.show() # this is way too boilerplate, I'd like to avoid it too. 
    do_some_work()
```

> What alternative to `%matplotlib` I can use to manipulate figures while a script is running in Python (not IPython)?

#### What solutions I've already investigated?

I currently found 3 way to get a plot show.

**1. `%pylab` / `%matplotlib`**

As [tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588071/tom) said, the use of `%pylab` should be avoided to prevent the namespace to be polluted.

```
>>> %pylab
>>> plot([1,2,3,4])
```

This solution is sweet, the plot is non-blocking, there is no need for an additionnal `show()`, I can still add a grid with `grid()` afterwards and I can close, resize or zoom on my figure with no additional issues.

Unfortunately the `%matplotlib` command is only available on IPython.

**2. `from pylab import *` or `from matplotlib.pyplot import plt`**

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> plot([1,2,3,4])
```

Things are quite different here. I need to add the command `show()` to display my figure which is blocking. I cannot do anything but closing the figure to execute the next command such as `grid()` which will have no effect since the figure is now closed...

** 3. `from pylab import *` or `from matplotlib.pyplot import plt` + `ion()`**
Some suggestions recommend to use the `ion()` command as follow:

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> ion()
>>> plot([1,2,3,4])
>>> draw()
>>> pause(0.0001)
```

Unfortunately, even if the plot shows, I cannot close the figure manually. I will need to execute `close()` on the terminal which is not very convenient. Moreover the need for two additional commands such as `draw(); pause(0.0001)` is not what I am expecting.

#### Summary

With `%pylab`, everything is wonderful, but I cannot use it outside of IPython

With `from pylab import *` followed by a `plot`, I get a blocking behavior and  all the power of IPython is wasted.

`from pylab import *` followed by `ion` offers a nice alternative to the previous one, but I have to use the weird `pause(0.0001)` command that leads to a window that I cannot close manually (I know that the `pause` is not needed with some backends. I am using `WxAgg` which is the only one that works well on `Cygwin x64`.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943731/reliably-show-matplotlib-0-99-to-1-3-1-figures-without-blocking) advices to use `matplotlib.interactive(True)`. Unfortunately it does not work and gives the same behavior as `ion()` does.

Comment: As a side note: its not recommended to use `pylab` at all anymore; we should import `matplotlib.pyplot` and `numpy` separately instead to prevent namespaces getting polluted. See here: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `do_some_work` function to the following and it should work.

```
def do_some_work(): 
    plt.pause(3)
```

For interactive backends `plt.pause(3)` starts the event loop for 3 seconds so that it can process your resize events. Note that [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pause) says that it is an experimental function and that for complex animations you should use the [animation module](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#module-matplotlib.animation).

The, `%pylab` and `%matplotlib` magic commands also start an event loop, which is why user interaction with the plots is possible. Alternatively, you can start the event loop with `%gui wx`, and turn it off with `%gui`. You can use the [IPython.lib.guisupport.is_event_loop_running_wx()](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.guisupport.html#functions) function to test if it is running.

The reason for using `ion()` or `ioff()` is very well explained in the ['What is interactive mode'](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode) page. In principle, user interaction is possible without IPython. However, I could not get the interactive-example from that page to work with the `Qt4Agg` backend, only with the `MacOSX` backend (on my Mac). I didn't try with the `WX` backend.

**Edit**

I did manage to get the interactive-example to work with the Qt4Agg backend by using PyQt4 instead of PySide (so by setting `backend.qt4 : PyQt4` in my `~/.config/matplotlibrc` file). I think the example doesn't work with all backends. I submitted an issue [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5517).

**Edit 2**

I'm afraid I can't think of a way of manipulating the figure while a long calculation is running, without using threads. As you mentioned: Matplotlib doesn't start a thread, and neither does IPython. The %pylab and %matplotlib commands alternate between processing commands from the read-eval-print loop and letting the GUI processing events for a short time. They do this sequentially.

In fact, I'm unable to reproduce your behavior, even with the %matplotlib or %pylab magic. (Just to be clear: in `ipython` I first call `%matplotlib` and then `%run yourscript.py`). The %matplotlib magic puts Matplotlib in interactive-mode, which makes the `plt.show()` call non-blocking so that the `do_some_work` function is executed immediately. However, during the `time.sleep(3)` call, the figure is unresponsive (this becomes even more apparent if I increase the sleeping period). I don't understand how this can work at your end.

Unless I'm wrong you'll have to break up your calculation in smaller parts and use `plt.pause` (or even better, the animation module) to update the figures.

Comment: Well, this is exactly where I want to go. The magic is obviously inside `%gui wx`. Unfortunately `IPython.lib.guisupport.get_app_wx` is not available in my IPython. How can I access to this manually?

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused about what your actual goal is. I thought you wanted user interaction without depending on IPython. The `get_app_wx` function and the `%gui` [magic-command](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) are both IPython functionality. I only included them to explain why the `%pylab` option works, sorry if that wasn't clear. The actual solution is to replace `time.sleep` with `plt.pause` in the `do_some_work` function. Did that work for you? And the [Interactive example](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode), does that work?

Comment: I mean we still not have a solution, but at least you explained some magic. I may still do `import IPython` from my standalone script to enable the `IPython.lib.guisupport.get_app_wx`. Unfortunately this does not work yet.  The `ion()` does not work as explained on my question.

Comment: What version of IPython do you use? `get_app_wx` has been there since 2010 so it should be available unless you use an ancient version. Also can you please explain why you think using `get_app_wx` is a viable solution? You still are depending on IPython in that case. IMHO the real solution is to use `plt.pause` in the `do_some_work` function but you haven't given any feedback on that yet.

Comment: Using `plt.pause` and `do_some_work` does not work because during all the processing of `do_some_work`, the figure is not refreshed. The user cannot *manipulate the figure while `do_some_work` is running*. It seems the only solution that meet my needs is `%matplotlib`. I discovered that this magic function is in fact hiding a call to `get_app_wx`. If I can just use it inside my script by using it I would be happy. The main problem comes that I cannot use a magic function inside a standalone script even if I do `import IPython`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95548/discussion-between-titusjan-and-nowox).

Comment: IPython `4.0.0` with Python `2.7.10`

Comment: If you run a long a long calculation in `do_some_work` it might help to call `plt.flush_events()` once in a while. For instance at the end of a for loop.

Comment: Could you provide an example based on on my *example* where you do not touch at `do_some_work` function ? You may use anything such as `guisupport`, but the magic commands `%pylab/%matplotlib` and I give you the bounty. The figures must remain responsive (ability to resize, zoom or  close them). The app should not close before all the figures are closed.

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to keep using IPython, since it manages the GUI event loop for you (that's what pylab/pylot does). 
I tried interactive plotting in a normal interpreter and it worked the way it is expected, even without calling `ion()` (Debian unstable, Python 3.4.3+, Matplotlib 1.4.2-3.1). If I recall it right, it's a fairly new feature in Matplotlib.

Alternatively, you can also use Matplotlib's animation capabilities to update a plot periodically:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

plt.ion()

tt = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
freq = 1  # parameter for sine
t0 = time.time()  # for measuring ellapsed time

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


def draw_func(i):
    """ This function gets called repeated times """ 
    global freq  # needed because freq is changed in this function
    xx = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*tt)/freq
    ax.set_title("Passed Time: %.1f s, " % (time.time()-t0) +
                 "Parameter i=%d" % i)
    ax.plot(tt, xx, label="$f=%d$ Hz" % freq)
    ax.legend()
    freq += 1


# call draw_func every 3 seconds 1 + 4 times (first time is initialization):
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, draw_func,  np.arange(4), interval=3000,
                              repeat=False)
# plt.show()
```

Checkout [matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html?highlight=funcanimation) for details. You'll find further examples in the [examples section](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/).

Comment: With your example, you showed me that `matplotlib.animation` will not solve my problem. In parallel, I asked [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763328/multiple-figures-with-python) where I would like to plot several figures using threads. Unfortunately threads do not play well with IPython or interactive matplotlib.

Comment: Yes threads and the GUI loop do not work well together. If you want true concurrency, put each matplotlib window into a own process - IPython.parallel (https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/) can be used for that and it plays nice on multicore machines (it can be used without the IPython interpreter). Unfortunately, I never really used  IPython.parallel that way - so I cannot give you an example for that.