# How to put Python 3.4 matplotlib in non-interactive mode?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,np.pi,0.001)
f = np.sin(x)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(x,f)
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Sine')
```

Here, I want Python to save the figure *after* I closed the figure window. Of course, this isn't very useful, but in the original code I want to manipulate the figure graphically and then save the changes.

The above code worked fine with my last Python version (Version 2.? with Debian), but since I changed to SuSe 13.2 with Python 3.4 it simply runs the whole code without a stop.

There do exist other threads on this topic like [Matplotlib python show() returns immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280171/matplotlib-python-show-returns-immediately) but those solutions don't work for me - I tried `matplotlib.interactive(False)` and choosing various different backends for matplotlib (currently I'm using `'QT4Agg'`).

Comment: What happers when you move`plt.ioff()` before `plt.figure`? In principle, you should call it before you create figures and maybe matplotlib for Python 3.4 is more strict on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help either. I even put matplotlib.interactive(False) in the header, without any effect.

Comment: Are you running this code within an IPython session? You should mention this in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Please use the `Agg` backend. It is non interactive and it solves this issue. To set a matplotlib backend you need to call `use` method as shown below.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Comment: Probably not current anymore: `UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.`