# Cannot get the pyplot multiple times

Tags: c++, python-2.7

I use Embedding Python in C++, in my program, I have to run the python module many times. Unfortunately, the `plt.show()` only gets the figure one time, the others get the null figure

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Circle
import time
def show(x,y,x1,y1):
    fig=plt.figure()
    fig.gca().invert_yaxis()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cir1 = Circle(xy = (x1, y1), radius=0.02, alpha=0.5)
    ax1.add_patch(cir1)
    print len(x)
    print x1
    ax1.set_title('Scatter Plot')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')  
    ax1.scatter(x,y,c = 'r',marker = 'o')
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(1)
    plt.close()
    return 'ok'
```

[image]

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11364849/5994041), maybe you need to call `fig.show()` first, otherwise it just dies.